# Bind class based on knockout foreach index

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I need to make the first item in a tab group, active. I am attempting to use the index for the foreach, and set the class based on that.

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: TemplateGroups">
        <li data-bind="css: {active: $index==0}"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tb1"><span data-bind="text: Description"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

However, the item isn't becoming active. What am I missing?

Comment: $index is an observable and is updated whenever the index of the item changes (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).  And an observable is a function.  Then, you are comparing a function with a number, and always is false.  You should use `active: $index() == 0`.  Example:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgOgNd.

Comment: Thanks. Worked. Can you make an answer, and I'll mark and close. Thanks. Rookie error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

*`$index` is an observable and is updated whenever the index of the item changes*

And an observable is a function.

Then, you are comparing a function with a number, and always is false.

You should use active: `$index() == 0` or `$index() === 0`.

Example: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgOgNd)